# Django rest ModelViewSet many-to-many create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have my model relationships as following: A *Reader* will have a *Wishlist* and a Wishlist will have many *Book*s:

```
class Reader(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    # A library has many readers
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='readers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...
    # A library has many books
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Record the date whenever a new book is added, it will be helpful for showing new arrivals
    when_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null= True)
    reader = models.ManyToManyField('Reader', related_name='wishlist')
```

My serializers:

```
class ReaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password')

    class Meta:
        model = Reader
        #fields = '__all__'
        #depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'address', 'dob', 'which_library')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
        instance.which_library = validated_data.get('which_library', instance.which_library)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
        user.set_password(user_data['password'])
        user.save()
        reader = Reader.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return reader   


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    wishlist = ReaderSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

I can already perform CRUD operations with Reader, I want to now add books to a specific Reader's wishlist. My view:

```
class ReaderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReaderSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        readers = Reader.objects.filter(which_library=self.kwargs.get('library_id'))
        return readers

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def wishlist(self):
        return Response('OK')
```

URL that I hit:

`router.register(r'readers/(?P<library_id>[0-9]+)', ReaderViewSet, base_name='readers')`

Here I am expecting that on hitting `api/readers/<library_id>/<book_id>/wishlist/add`I will be able to perform 
add operation to the Wishlist.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use detail_route's argument `url_path` to change url of endpoint. Also you can add additional arguments like book_id directly to detail_routed method, so your method can look like this:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'], url_path='(?P<book_id>[0-9]+)/wishlist/add')
def wishlist(self, library_id=None, book_id=None):
    reader = self.request.user.reader 
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
    reader.wishlist.add(book) 
    return Response('OK')
```

And it should be accessible from `api/readers/<library_id>/<book_id>/wishlist/add` url.

Comment: One quick question: It generated URL like /api/readers/{library_id}/{id}/{book_id}/wishlist/add/ - where this extra {id} is coming from?

Comment: @Nitish looks like `detail_route` required `pk` in the url to detect current object. In this case you can try to remove `book_id` from `url_path` argument and rename book_id to `pk` in wishlist method..

Comment: It didn't really changed anything in url i.e. @detail_route(methods=['post'], url_path='/wishlist/add')
    def wishlist(self, library_id=None, pk=None)